# How to convert(re-code) extensions from OpenCart 1.5 to 2.3

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I have several extensions I once made for OpenCart 1.5 and I want to "convert" them to OpenCart 2.3.0.2.

I'm having a hard time figuring how to do the following for 2.3.0.2:

```
    echo "Free Items Disabler started.<br>";
    $sqll = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'";

    $result = mysql_query($sqll)or die(mysql_error());
    $antall = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo "Products to check: ".$antall."<br>";
 ... 
$this->session->data['success'] = 'Free Items Disabler has
 disabled ' . $products_changed . ' products with no price!';
```

- How do I print messages to the page? Echo doesn't show anywhere.
- How do I count the query results? The page always stops working when I try.

I've tried looking at other 2.3-extensions to figure it out, but I can't find any that do similar things. I've spent two days trying to figure this out.

Comment: I managed to get the counting right, now I need to print the messages to the user somehow

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) ");
$num = $query->rows;
...
$this->session->data['success'] = 'Free Items Disabler has disabled ' . $products_changed . ' products with no price!';
```